# Amazon Turk -- Trouble Getting started, AWS documentation little to no use

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mechanicalturk

I have been combing through the AWS MTurk documentation for hours and it is of little to no help for getting started on MTurk.

I am trying to have people upload small vid based on a set of instructions that I will provide. I am on the requester sandbox and I see no way to integrate anything off of the API reference. I am trying to put a `QuestionForm` with an `AnswerSpecification` displaying a `FileUploadAnswer`. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QuestionFormDataStructureArticle.html

From there I'm also struggling to understand how I would use the `GetFileUploadURL` to provide myself with the link to download the video uploaded by the user to approve them of their task.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetFileUploadURLOperation.html

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do file uploads via the Requester API, using the file upload question type. The QuestionForm documentation is decent, but the format is not necessarily intuitive - and being XML, is very strict.

An alternative would be to give workers some other way to send you the file, like Dropbox, etc.